# How many UILabels can be added to a View

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to add about 300 grids to a UIView,It is OK if I use 300 UILabels?
Or,besides UILabel,any better way to deal with it?

Comment: What kind of grid do you need?

Comment: @Krio like table grid in html, 10X30 grids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid means what you can make a UITableView with 300 rows and you can make any number of labels in your UIView

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577114/fast-2-dimensional-table-view). Other than that, I don't see a problem with UILabels, with that count, it might get slower though. Imagine how many objects you will be rendering...

Answer (score 0):

If you create a UITableView with reusable cells, only the visible cells will be populated at any one time, so only those UILabels (assuming one or more per cell) will actually exist at any one time. Not a problem.